# In what connection have to be rational parameters and irrational number for $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ to be rational number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

a,b,c,d are nonzero rational numbers and x is irrational. In what connection have to be a, b, c, d so that $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is a rational number?

Any help or tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

If $\dfrac{ax+b}{cx+d}=\dfrac pq$ for some integers $p$ and $q$ ($q\ne0$), then $(aq-cp)x=dp-bq$. As $x$ is irrational, both $aq-cp$ and $dp-bq$ should be zero.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If the map $x\mapsto \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$ is invertible, then both it and its inverse clearly send rationals to rationals.